# Комментарии VK на localhost

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, виджет

Пытаюсь протестировать комментарии ВК на `localhost`:

```
<div class="vk-widget">
    <div id="vk_comments"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        VK.init({apiId: 5561345, onlyWidgets: true});
        VK.Widgets.Comments("vk_comments", {redesign: 1, limit: 20, width: "868", attach: "photo,video,link"});
    </script>
</div>
```

Но на месте виджета появляется следующее:

> Please specify correct base domain name in app settings, or use widget
>   only in 127.0.0.1/*

В настройках приложения прописан `127.0.0.1`, на сайт захожу через `127.0.0.1:8000`. Неужели дело в порте?

P.S.: на удалённом сервере виджет работает.

Comment: `127.0.0.1:8000` и прописать, не?

Comment: @andreymal не, ВК стирает порт

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что ВК работает только с портом 80. Если перебросить `localhost:8000` на 80, то всё начинает работать.

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8000
```

Comment: Получил подтверждение от службы поддержки ВК. Все так: "Адреса с портами у нас не поддерживаются, так что попробуйте указать просто localhost в адресе сайта."